# CSS Background Image appears very small than orignial size of the image

Tags: css

The  Background Image  for the boxF appears very small than orignial size of the image.

```
<style type="text/css">
#boxA, #boxB, #boxC, #boxD, #boxE, #boxF  {
float:left;padding:10px;margin:10px;-moz-user-select:none;
}
#boxA { background-color: #6633FF; width:75px; height:75px;  }
#boxB { background-color: #FFFFFF; width:175px; height:200px; }
#boxC { background-color: #66FFFF; width:75px; height:75px;  }
#boxD { background-color: #6600FF; width:75px; height:75px;  }
#boxF { background-image: url("http://www.wesellcoffee.com/media/large%20platter%2011.jpg");
   background-size:100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}  
#boxE { background-color: #60330F; width:75px; height:75px;  }
</style>
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesrod9000/kjdq5wod/6/)

Comment: Since `#boxF` does not have its own width/height it takes its size to zero (plus the padding, plus a margin as specified in the first line of CSS).  Adding width/height will display the original image as 100% of the given width/height as specified in the definition for `#boxF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, your `#boxF` div is empty, thus it has 0 width and 0 height, and the only size it has is that 10px padding you gave to everything. Just give it a width and height and you'll be fine, [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcyd1kgh/)

```
#boxA, #boxB, #boxC, #boxD, #boxE, #boxF {
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    -moz-user-select:none;
}
#boxA {
    background-color: #6633FF;
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
}
#boxB {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width:175px;
    height:200px;
}
#boxC {
    background-color: #66FFFF;
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
}
#boxD {
    background-color: #6600FF;
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
}
#boxF {
    background-image: url("http://www.wesellcoffee.com/media/large%20platter%2011.jpg");
    background-size:100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:600px;
    height:537px;
}
#boxE {
    background-color: #60330F;
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
}
```